# clickonce installation question

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I have 2 servers. One is production and testing servers.

Now, I have a WPF application which sitting in both production and testing servers. How can i install the WPF app in my local machine with both from production and testing servers? I keep getting an error the same signature has been installed.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a separate ClickOnce package for each environment. Each package will need to  have a different assemblyIdentity name. Look in the deployment manifest (*.application) file for the assemblyIdentity element. The name attribute of this element must be different for each environment. It will look something like:

```
<assemblyIdentity 
    name="Product_TEST"
    version="2.5.44.19347" 
    publicKeyToken="82e7b44bd73eeecd" 
    language="neutral" 
    processorArchitecture="msil" 
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
```

We use names like: Product_TEST, Product_UAT, Product_PROD to distinguish between each ClickOnce instance. Using this method we are able to install multiple instances of a product side-by-side on a client PC.

This means that you need to create a separate ClickOnce package for each environment. The deployment manifest will be different for each and therefore each package will have different signing signatures (if you are using signed packages). We used to use msbuild ClickOnce targets to build separate packages for all of our environments but have recently changed to building one generic package and have a custom built configuration tool that performs the ClickOnce repackaging as needed. You can also use Mage.

Comment: I cant figure out how to change the name attribute. I am using msbuild with /t:publish

Comment: If you are using the /t:Publish inbuilt target then you will need to edit the name via the Project Properties within VisualStudio. Open the project properties, click the Publish tab and click Options. I use the GenerateApplicationManifest and GenerateDeploymentManifest msbuild targets directly in my build scripts therefore I can set the properties as needed.

Comment: Perhaps this has changed, bu tI don't see how to do this.  In all my testing all I've been able to accomplish is getting the identity name set from the AssemblyName, but it still produces the wrong value.